# Facebook Custom Audience pixel on multiple websites

Tags: facebook

I have one Facebook Ads account and two different e-commerce websites (which I own/manage).

I would like to make separate custom audiences based on users which visit specific URLs on two separate websites/domains and then create two SEPARATE ads that can retarget (separately) those groups/audiences.

Can I use **one Custom Audience pixel** and use it on **two separate websites**/domains?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can use the same pixel on both sites, then create audiences from it based on the url.  Here's more information on how this works: [Facebook: Configure your Audience Rules](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/website-custom-audiences/getting-started#configure-rules)